# how to discern where to use "whereas" or "although"

Tags: conjunctions

A. He didn't take an umbrella whereas it was rainy.

B. He didn't take an umbrella, but it was rainy.

C.  He didn't take an umbrella although it was rainy.

Would you please show me which of these could be correct?

Comment: He did not take an umbrella whereas she did take one.

Comment: A & C sound  correct grammatically; although and whereas have been used as subordinate conjunctions.  On the other hand, B doesn't sound OK as the word but is a coordinating conjunction. I think the sentence should be "It was rainy but he didn't take an umbrella.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/despite

Answer (score 4):

(C) is the correct sentence.

*Whereas* is used to show a contrast like "I write with my right hand, whereas you write with your left hand."

(B) could also be correct, but it would have a different meaning. (C) implies that he knew it was rainy, but (B) could mean that he didn't know. Sentence B would make more sense that way if it were 2 sentences:

> He didn't take an umbrella. BUT IT WAS RAINY. **DUN DUN DUN**

You use *although* to show that even though it was rainy, he still didn't bring an umbrella. He just doesn't care.

Answer (score -1):

As a conjunction, *although* shows surprise, while *whereas* and *but* show a contrast.

Therefore, choice c is correct.

Comment: @thengvietnam please add references to your answer